# Неправильно отображается страница /page/2 Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывел пагинацию после постов встроенной функцией `the_posts_pagination`
Пагинация вывелась, но проблема появляется тогда, когда переходишь на вторую страницу блога (blog/page/2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Такое ощущение, как будто сбивается css стили**

Ссылка на блог: http://2178559.rp411870.web.hosting-test.net/blog/
Ссылка на вторую страницу блога: http://2178559.rp411870.web.hosting-test.net/blog/page/2/

```html
<?php get_header() ?>

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/breadcrumbs'); ?>

<section class="post_blog_bg primary-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            
            <div class="col-md-8">
                
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article class="blog_post">
                                <h4> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h4>
                                    
                                    <div class="blog_category">
                                        <ul> 
                                            <li> <?php the_category(', ') ?></li>
                                            
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>  
                                    
                                    <div class="blog_text">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li> | </li>
                                            <li> Post By : <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> </li>
                                            <li> | </li>
                                            <li>  On : <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?> </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="blog_post_img">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> Continue reading <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    
                                
                            </article>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
            
            </div>


                
            <?php get_sidebar() ?>
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

functions.php

```html
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_scripts' );
function test_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript0', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/agency.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.countdown.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript6', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plugin.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery_002.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript9', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery_003.js');
    // css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
}

// Поддержка темой определенных функций

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'test_support');
function test_support(){
    
    load_theme_textdomain('test');

    add_theme_support('title-tag');

    add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
        'height' => 31, 
        'width' => 134, 
        'flex-height' => true
    ));

    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(730,446);

    add_theme_support('html5', array(
        'search-form', 
        'comment-form', 
        'comment-list', 
        'gallery', 
        'caption'
    ));

    add_theme_support('post-formats', array(
        'aside',
        'image',
        'video',
        'gallery',
    ));

    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary menu');

}

add_filter('excerpt_more', function($more){
    return '...';
});


// breadcrumbs

function test_the_breadcrumb(){
    global $post;
    if(!is_home()){ 
       echo '<li><a href="'.site_url().'"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li> <li> / </li> ';
        if(is_single()){ // posts
        the_category(', ');
        echo " <li> / </li> ";
        echo '<li>';
            the_title();
        echo '</li>';
        }
        elseif (is_page()) { // pages
            if ($post->post_parent ) {
                $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
                $breadcrumbs = array();
                while ($parent_id) {
                    $page = get_page($parent_id);
                    $breadcrumbs[] = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a></li>';
                    $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
                }
                $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
                foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo $crumb . '<li> / </li> ';
            }
            echo the_title();
        }
        elseif (is_category()) { // category
            global $wp_query;
            $obj_cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $current_cat = $obj_cat->term_id;
            $current_cat = get_category($current_cat);
            $parent_cat = get_category($current_cat->parent);
            if ($current_cat->parent != 0) 
                echo(get_category_parents($parent_cat, TRUE, ' <li> / </li> '));
            single_cat_title();
        }
        elseif (is_search()) { // search pages
            echo 'Search results "' . get_search_query() . '"';
        }
        elseif (is_tag()) { // tags
            echo single_tag_title('', false);
        }
        elseif (is_day()) { // archive (days)
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></li> <li> / </li> ';
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a></li> <li> / </li> ';
            echo get_the_time('d');
        }
        elseif (is_month()) { // archive (months)
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a></li> <li> / </li>';
            echo get_the_time('F');
        }
        elseif (is_year()) { // archive (years)
            echo get_the_time('Y');
        }
        elseif (is_author()) { // authors
            global $author;
            $userdata = get_userdata($author);
            echo '<li>Posted ' . $userdata->display_name . '</li>';
        } elseif (is_404()) { // if page not found
            echo '<li>Error 404</li>';
        }
     
        if (get_query_var('paged')) // number of page
            echo ' (' . get_query_var('paged').'- page)';
     
    } else { // home
       $pageNum=(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
       if($pageNum>1)
          echo '<li><a href="'.site_url().'"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true">Home</a></li> <li> / </li> '.$pageNum.'- page';
       else
          echo '<li><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</li>';
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
function register_post_types(){

    register_taxonomy('event_type', 'events', [
        'labels' => [
            'name'                     => 'События', // основное название во множественном числе
            'singular_name'            => 'Событие', // название единичного элемента таксономии
            'menu_name'                => 'Типы событий', // Название в меню. По умолчанию: name.
            'all_items'                => 'Все события',
            'edit_item'                => 'Изменить событие',
            'view_item'                => 'Просмотр события', // текст кнопки просмотра записи на сайте (если поддерживается типом)
            'update_item'              => 'Обновить событие',
            'add_new_item'             => 'Добавить новое событие',
            'new_item_name'            => 'Название нового события',
            'parent_item'              => 'Родительское событие', // только для таксономий с иерархией
            'parent_item_colon'        => 'Родительское событие:',
            'search_items'             => 'Искать события',
            'popular_items'            => 'Популярные события', // для таксономий без иерархий
            'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Разделяйте события запятыми',
            'add_or_remove_items'      => 'Добавить или удалить события',
            'choose_from_most_used'    => 'Выбрать из часто используемых событий',
            'not_found'                => 'Событий не найдено',
            'back_to_items'            => '← Назад к событиям',
        ],
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
    ]);

    register_post_type( 'events', [
        'label'  => null,
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => 'События', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Событие', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить событие', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление события', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование события', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'Новое событие', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть событие', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Искать события', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено событий', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'События', // название меню
        ],
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
        // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
        'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        //'capability_type'   => 'post',
        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => [ 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
        'taxonomies'          => [], //можно выбрать 'category'
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
    ] );
}

// Вывести события на главный блог

function add_events_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'events' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_events_to_query' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите на то что есть functions.php

Спасибо, что дали код, тут вероятно ошибка, которая не дает выполнению нужной функции:

```
    } else { // home
       $pageNum=(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
       if($pageNum>1)
          echo '<li><a href="'.site_url().'"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true">Home</a></li> <li> / </li> '.$pageNum.'- page';
       else
          echo '<li><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</li>';
    }
}
```

завтра я посмотрю по коду, сегодня уже не успею. И отредактирую свой ответ с нужным куском, что дописать. Спасибо.

[image: Смотрите в этом куске кода, тут ошибка, по циклу выводит лишнее]

Также посмотрите ошибки в консоле, их нужно исправить в первую очередь.

Comment: скинул код functions php

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).